# How to create this new dataframe by manipulating existing data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a data frame with years and the respective months in the columns.

I am looking to transform the data frame to show YYYY-MM in the first column and the respective values on the second column.

Data frame to transform:

[image: Data frame to transform]

Ideal outcome after transformation:

[image: Ideal outcome after transformation]

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=["Year"], value_vars=months, var_name="Month", value_name="CPI")` which assumes `months` is a list of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially accomplish this with:

```
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=["Year"], value_vars=months, var_name="Month", value_name="CPI")
```

That will look like:

```
     Year Month  CPI
0    1984   Jan 0.48
1    1985   Jan 0.47
2    1986   Jan 0.64
3    1987   Jan 0.52
4    1988   Jan 1.00
```

You can get it to look like what you want pretty easily from there. For example:

```
# helpful
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
month_map = dict(zip(months, [i for i in range(1,13)]))

# get it to look like your ideal outcome
df_melted = df_melted.replace({"Month": month_map})
ym = [f"{y}-{m:02d}" for y, m in df_melted[["Year", "Month"]].values]
df_melted.insert(0, "Year-Month", ym)
df_melted.drop(["Year", "Month"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Now it will look like your desired outcome.